# Sequential vs parallel solution memory usage

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, memory-leaks, task

I have a slight issue with the following scenario:
I'm given a list of ID values, I need to run a SELECT query (where the ID is a parameter), then combine all the result sets as one big one and return it to the caller.

Since the query might run for minutes per ID (that's another issue, but at the moment I consider it as a given fact), and there can be 1000s of IDs in the input) I tried to use tasks. With that approach I experience a slow, but solid increase in memory use.

As a test, I made a simple sequential solution too, this has normal memory usage graph, but as expected, very slow. There's an increase while it's running, but then everything drops back to the normal level when it's finished.

Here's the skeleton of code:

```
public class RowItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //the rest of the properties
}


public List<RowItem> GetRowItems(List<int> customerIDs)
{
    // this solution has the memory leak
    var tasks = new List<Task<List<RowItem>>>();
    foreach (var customerID in customerIDs)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => return ProcessCustomerID(customerID));
        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    while (tasks.Any())
    {
        var index = Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());
        var task = tasks[index];
        rowItems.AddRange(task.Result);
        tasks.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    // this works fine, but slow
    foreach (var customerID in customerIDs)
    {
        rowItems.AddRange(ProcessCustomerID(customerID)));
    }

    return rowItems;
}

private List<RowItem> ProcessCustomerID(int customerID)
{
    var rowItems = new List<RowItem>();
    using (var conn = new OracleConnection("XXX"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM ...";
        using (var command = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    dataTable.Load(dataReader);
                    rowItems = dataTable
                               .Rows
                               .OfType<DataRow>()
                               .Select(
                                   row => new RowItem
                                   {
                                       ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
                                       Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
                                       //the rest of the properties
                                   })
                               .ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
    return rowItems;
}
```

What am I doing wrong when using tasks? According to [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx), I don't need to bother disposing them manually, but there's barely anything else. I guess ProcessCustomerID is OK, as it's called in both variations.

**update**
To log the current memory usage I used `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64`, but I noticed the problem in Task Manager >> Processes

Comment: I think that you should combine the sequential and parallel approaches, by limiting the number of tasks to the number of cores in your system, each task processing sequentially a number of Ids equal to IdsCount / CoresCount (adjusted with division remainder!).

Comment: I don't think limiting by cores does anything; these are IO bound. It might be something related to the Oracle driver not giving up memory. You shouldn't have to remove the tasks from the list or dispose them.

Comment: @Szeki: How did you measure memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Using entity framework your ProcessCustomerID method could look like:

```
List<RowItem> rowItems;
using(var ctx = new OracleEntities()){
  rowItems = ctx.Customer
    .Where(o => o.id == customerID)
    .Select(
      new RowItem
      {
        ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]),
        Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
        //the rest of the properties
      }
    ).ToList();
}
return rowItems;
```

Unless you are transferring large amounts of data like images, video, data or blobs this should be near instantaneous with 1k data as result.

If it is unclear what is taking time, and you use pre 10g oracle, it would be really hard to monitor this. However if you use entity framework you can attach monitoring to it! http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof

At least a year ago Oracle supported entity framework 5.

In sequential they are executed one by one, in parallel they literally get started all at same time consuming your resources and creating deadlocks.

Comment: The query itself runs for minutes even in PL/SQL Developer. I could use EF and import all involved views and then I could rewrite the whole logic in c#. But I'm more interested in figuring out why the sequential execution works normally, while the version with tasks causes constant increase in memory usage. Or you think the root of the whole problem is the way I'm retrieving the data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have any evidences for  a memory leak in the parallel execution.

May be Garbage Collection occurs at different times and that’s why experienced two different readings. You cannot expect it release memory real time. .Net garbage collection occurs only when required.  Have a look at “[Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx)”

Task Manager or `Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64` may not very accurate way to find memory leaks. If you do so, at least make sure you call full garbage collection and wait for pending finalizers prior reading memory counters.

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```